# Xamarin.Forms Entry with auto thousand and decimal separator

Tags: xamarin, decimal, xamarin.forms, currency

I have a Xamarin.Forms entry with numeric keyboard that will represent a pt-BR REAL currency (999.999,99). When I type numbers in the numeric keyboard, the comma(representing decimal) and dot(representind thousand) needs to be added automatically while I am typing.

To achieve this goal, what is the best practice/design pattern in Xamarin.Forms to work in all platforms?

Comment: You will have to create CustomRenders and do it per platform for best results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use a TextChanged event.  The first step I removed the $ from the string so that I could parse the new text value.  If it fails to parse, that means that the user added a non-digit character and we just revert to whatever the old text was.

Next, we detect if user ADDED a new digit and its to the RIGHT of the decimal (example 1.532).  If so we, we move the decimal to the right by * 10.   Do the opposite for a DELETION.

OH, and almost forgot about when we initialize the number! The first digit we enter will be a whole number so we * 100 to make sure the first digit we enter starts as fraction.

Once we got our decimal correct, we display it using `num.ToString("C");`

Working Example:
[image]

xaml:

```
<Entry                 
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    TextChanged="OnFinancialTextChanged"
    Placeholder="$10.00"
    Text="{Binding RetailPrice}"/>
```

Then in the cs

.cs:

```
private void OnFinancialTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = (Entry)sender;
                   
    var amt = e.NewTextValue.Replace("$", "");


    if (decimal.TryParse(amt, out decimal num))
    {
        // Init our number
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.OldTextValue))
        {
            num = num / 100;
        }
        // Shift decimal to right if added a decimal digit
        else if (num.DecimalDigits() > 2 && !e.IsDeletion())
        {
            num = num * 10;
        }
        // Shift decimal to left if deleted a decimal digit
        else if(num.DecimalDigits() < 2 && e.IsDeletion())
        {
            num = num / 10;
        }

        entry.Text = num.ToString("C");
    }
    else
    {
        entry.Text = e.OldTextValue;
    }
}
```

I created these Extension methods to help with the logic

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int DecimalDigits(this decimal n)
    {
        return n.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                .SkipWhile(c => c != '.')
                .Skip(1)
                .Count();
    }

    public static bool IsDeletion(this TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.OldTextValue) && e.OldTextValue.Length > e.NewTextValue.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: How you avoided the loop event? Every time you change the value then the OnFinancialTextChanged event occurs again and so again etc..

Comment: I haven't looked at this code in a while but when we used it, it did not create an infinite loop because setting entry.Text did not trigger the OnFinancialTextChange event.  If  you are experiencing an infinite loop,  I would try set `e.NewTextValue = num.ToString("C")` instead of entry.Text = numToString("C")

Comment: Nope, e.NewTextValue is only a get property. I tried also with a flag: set it false before assigning and then false it after. But it loops however.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a custom renderer.

I recommend to subclass `Entry` and subscribe to the `TextChanged` [event](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Entry.cs#L85). 
In there you would parse and reformat the current text and update the `Text` property.

Comment: If a change Text property in TextChanged event, it falls in a recursive loop.

Comment: Not true. The second time it triggers the event you will not be changing the text because you changed it before, so it'll not enter an infinite loop.

Comment: Also, if you put the keyboard type as Numeric, you only get `.` in the keypad. Also how will you handle different language and currency like Swedish?

Comment: Not sure what that has to do with the original question? If you have a hardware keyboard, you won't get any virtual keyboard at all...

Comment: Hardware keyboard on a mobile device is rare.

Comment: Numeric keyboard without "," is another issue that I will to solve. Right now, Android >= 4.4 in my language pt-BR has both "," and "." in numeric keyboard, but Android < 4.4 has not. WP8 and UWP has "," instead of "." when using pt-BR language. I have not tested on iOS.

Comment: I was looking at Xamarin official guide and noticed that there is some design patterns like Behaviors, Commands, ViewModel classes that are possible to achieve the same goal like using a custom renderer. What would be ideal to use? Why?