# Decimal First Price Entry

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

is there a way to achieve a PayPal like 'decimal-first' entry in  Xamarin Forms?

[image: example from PayPal]

I hope the screenshot is self explanatory. I basically want an instantaneous division of the input by 100. For an input of e.g. 3,85 I want it shown as
0,03
0,38
3,85
Is there a good way to implement this in Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by `TextChanged` event.
Here's the code below for your reference:

Xaml:

```
<Entry                 
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged"
  />
```

Code behind:

```
   private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
        {
            

            var entry = (Entry)sender;
            var amt = e.NewTextValue.Replace("$", "");


            if (decimal.TryParse(amt, out decimal num))
            {
                // Init our number
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.OldTextValue))
                {
                    num = num / 100;
                }

                // Shift decimal to right if added a decimal digit
                else if (num.DecimalDigits() > 2 && !e.IsDeletion())
                {
                    num = num * 10;
                }

                // Shift decimal to left if deleted a decimal digit
                else if (num.DecimalDigits() < 2 && e.IsDeletion())
                {
                    num = num / 10;
                }

                entry.Text = num.ToString("C");
            }

            else
            {
                entry.Text = e.OldTextValue;
            }
        }
    }


    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static int DecimalDigits(this decimal n)
        {
            return n.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

                    .SkipWhile(c => c != '.')

                    .Skip(1)

                    .Count();
        }

        public static bool IsDeletion(this TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.OldTextValue) && e.OldTextValue.Length > e.NewTextValue.Length;
        }

    }
```

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454280/9644964).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think, I experience, what's described in the comments of the original post, my App crashes everytime I try to enter a value. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tested it with VS 2019 and an emulator with Android 12- API 31 and it worked well when entering numeric value. Can you help confirm which line throws the exception to cause the app crash?

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about your question and got something you may want to.
Try to bind your textBox with property **Text="{Binding InputValue}**. Then implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface by typing `: INotifyPropertyChanged` to your main class.

Create `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler` named **PropertyChanged** and add required:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Don't forget to set property, by typing **InputValue = 0.00M** add **DataContext = this** below **InitializeComponent();** too.

It's very important to create fullprop like this:

```
private decimal inputValue;

public decimal InputValue
{
  get { return inputValue; }
  set
  {
    inputValue = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("InputValue");
  }
}
```

Now you have to set your textBox to be ReadOnly and add KeyDown event:

```
private void InputPriceTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  int num = 0;
  string stringVal = e.Key.ToString();

  if (stringVal.Length > 1)
  {
    if (stringVal.Contains("NumPad"))
    {
      num = Convert.ToInt32(stringVal.Substring(6));
    }
    else if (stringVal.Contains("D"))
    {
      num = Convert.ToInt32(stringVal.Substring(1));
    }
    else
    {
      return;
    }

    if (InputValue == 0.00M)
    {
      InputValue = 0.00M + (decimal)num / 100;
    }
    else
    {
      InputValue *= 10;
      InputValue += (decimal)num / 100;
    }
  }
}
```

It works for me, try it yourself!

This is a working version for WPF, but hopefully you'll change it into Xamarin (mobile devices don't have NumPad etc.)